# C# Тип "ConsoleColor" не допускает значение Null

Tags: c#, консоль, null

IDE пишет ошибку, что ConsoleColor не принимает значение `null`.

```cs
public static class ConsoleLogger {
    public static void Write(params object[] oo) {
        foreach(var o in oo) {
            if(o == null) 
                Console.ResetColor();       
            else if (o is ConsoleColor) 
                Console.ForegroundColor = o as ConsoleColor;
            else
                Console.Write(o.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score -1):

Тип `ConsoleColor` на самом деле является перечислением. Для того, чтобы разрешить пользователю вводить этот цвет, необходимо заставить его ввести число или строку с именем. Вам может очень помочь эта статья: [ConsoleColor Перечисление](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.consolecolor?view=net-6.0). Вот пример:

```cs
if(o == "12" || o == "red" || o == "Red") {
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
} // и все цвета
else if(o == String.Empty || o == " ") {
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

Про значение `null`: На основе перечислений можно создать обьект, но класс и перечисление - это абсолютно разные вещи.
Не принимает перечисление значение `null` по причине того, что обьект на основе перечисления не является ссылкой. Для ссылок `null` означает, что она не ссылается ни на что. Перечисление это не класс, и ему память выделяется по другому. Обьект на основе перечисления не может "не значить ничего": это как тип-значение по типу `int`. Больше про перечисления и классы можно прочитать здесь:

Классы: [Introduction to classes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes)

; Перечисления: [Enums](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/enums)